# How can i fit a very big element in a flexbox without expanding the parent container?

Tags: css

I have a flex layout. In one of the flex elements, theres an element with a height of 2500px. It needs to be scrollable, but also take all the space available.

The problem is that using flex, the long element makes its parent overflow outside the screen. It needs to fit the parent WITHOUT overflowing or making its parent element longer vertically.

Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-elbakyan-ro7jp?file=/index.html

EDIT: yes, Andrei Voicu's answer is correct.

However, i thought the solution to this question would solve my case, but i oversimplified the question and it doesnt resolve my specific situation.

If you want to see what my exact layout needed to be, heres is the codesandbox with the solved css:

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-currying-uh67e?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox is not enough, for what you need you can use a combination of flexbox and positioning.

1. Use flexbox to set the dimensions of the `overflow` container
2. Set `position: relative` on the `overflow` container
3. Add a wrapper child that extends as much as the `overflow` container, using `position: absolute` and has `overflow: auto`
4. Content inside this container will overflow while keeping in line with the flexbox layout

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.overflows {
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    
    overflow: auto;
}

.content {
    height: 300vh; // scrollable
}

.side {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: honeydew;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="overflows">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                scroll me
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="side">
        side content
    </div>
</div>
```